# How to put HTML code in JavaScript if() statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked all over the web for an answer to this, and all I can really find directed to my actual question is 'ajax' and I'm already using it, but that don't say what in it to use!

Here's my problem: I have HTML code(specifically a table with a form inside of it, but that doesn't matter), and I need the code to depend on a JavaScript variable grabbed from a cookie.

In the beginning of the form, naturally, I'd put my declarations for when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var login = 0;
    var myusername;
    var saves = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery.cookie('savedata')) {
            savedstats = jQuery.cookie('savedata').split('|');
            login = parseInt(savedstats[0]);
            myusername = parseInt(savedstats[1);
        } else {
            login = 0;
        }
    });
</script>
```

And I've tried many different ways, but.. No avail.

Comment: where should the html get added?

Comment: it is as simple as `$('some-element').append('some-html')`

Comment: *Where* do you have the HTML code? *How* should it depend on the cookie? *Why* do you think this should be done with JS?

Comment: Do you want to insert the username into the page?  Something like `$('.username').html(myusername)` and the HTML would be <span class="username"></span>

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var login = 0;
    if (login == 0){
        document.write('<li><a title="home"....</li>');
    }else{
        document.write('<li>Not valid</li>');
</script>
```

Is that what you want?

PS, this is a very very bad design

Comment: Not really... Here's a photo of what I want the code to be:
http://gyazo.com/a00073f85ad4bd0373df0efd7d9de2a3.png

Thanks for helping.. And sorry for not being descriptive enough.

Comment: There, Edited just for you